# Escape $ in powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, cmd, passwords, escaping

I use the following to quickly login to RDP:

```
echo "Connecting to 192.168.1.100"
$Server="192.168.1.100"
$User="Administrator"
$Password="Admin$Password"
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
```

Unfortunately AdminPassword does contain '$' character which breaks the thing. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using " " who take $x for a variable. Use ' ' and everything in it will be a character.

Comment: Using APOSTROPHE and QUOTATION MARK follows the same rule as on UNIX/Linux. Interpolation is only done when a QUOTATION MARK is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the backtick character `` ` `` (to the left of the `1` key on US keyboards) to escape special characters - see [About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7).

This escapes the dollar sign as well, so your code would become:

```bsh
$Password="Admin`$Password"
```